# ¿Es "la azúcar" o "el azúcar"?

Tags: gramática, género, artículos

I'm a bit confused: Is "sugar" "la azúcar" or "el azúcar"?

If both are correct: Does it depend on the context? Are there more words where both articles can be used?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* tells us:

> [**azúcar**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=az%FAcar)
>
> 1. ‘Sustancia cristalizada usada para endulzar’. **Es válido su uso en ambos géneros, aunque, si va sin especificativo, es mayoritario su empleo en masculino**: *«Mientras revolvíamos el azúcar, Alfonso tomó la palabra»* (Ibargüengoitia Crímenes [Méx. 1979]); *«Se trató sin éxito de facilitar la inmigración de colonos [...] para fomentar el cultivo de la azúcar»* (Silvestrini/LSánchez Puerto Rico [P. Rico 1987]). Cuando lleva un adjetivo especificativo, este puede ir asimismo en cualquiera de los dos géneros, aunque suele predominar el femenino: *«Les preparaban una exquisita compota acaramelada con azúcar prieta»* (Sarduy Pájaros [Cuba 1993]); *«Puedes aromatizar la nata con azúcar avainillado»* (Arguiñano Recetas [Esp. 1996]). En plural, lleve o no especificativo, es claramente mayoritario el masculino: *«Ponga el agua a calentar e incorpore ambos azúcares»* (Domingo Sabor [Esp. 1992]). También es predominantemente masculino con el sentido de ‘hidrato de carbono simple’, tanto en singular como en plural.

That is, *it is valid to use both genders, although if no descriptive adjective is used the masculine form is the most usual*.

Note though that it also mentions:

> 2. Este sustantivo **tiene, además, la particularidad de admitir su uso con la forma *el* del artículo y un adjetivo en forma femenina, a pesar de no comenzar por /a/ tónica**: *«Se ponen en una ensaladera las yemas y el azúcar molida»* (Ortega Recetas [Esp. 1972]). Se trata de un resto del antiguo uso de la forma el del artículo ante sustantivos femeninos que comenzaban por vocal, tanto átona como tónica, algo que era normal en el español medieval (→ el, 2.1).

Meaning *it also has the distinctive feature of allowing the use of the article* el *and an adjective in the feminine form, even if [azúcar] does not begin with a stressed /a/*.

---

As per your second question:

> Are there more words where both articles can be used?

I can think on [**mar**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=mar):

> **mar**
>
> 1. ‘Masa de agua salada’. **Este sustantivo, neutro en latín, se ha usado en español en ambos géneros. En el español general actual es masculino**: «Estar cerca del mar, sobre el mar, por el mar. Siento ante él una sensación de libertad» (VMatas Suicidios [Esp. 1991]); **pero entre las gentes de mar (marineros, pescadores, etc.) es frecuente su empleo en femenino, que también abunda en poesía**: «¿Y en días de temporal, cuando las olas embisten, cuando la mar se pone brava?» (Gironella Hombres [Esp. 1986]). De ahí que se emplee en femenino en las expresiones que describen su estado (mar arbolada, mar calma, mar gruesa, mar picada, mar rizada, mar tendida, etc.) o en locuciones propias del lenguaje marinero, como alta mar o hacerse a la mar. También es femenino en algunas otras frases o locuciones, como cagarse en la mar (para expresar enfado), pelillos a la mar (para expresar reconciliación) o la mar de (‘mucho o muy’). Sin embargo, es masculino en un mar de (‘abundancia o gran cantidad de’), que forma parte de las locuciones estar hecho un mar de dudas (‘dudar mucho’) o estar hecho un mar de lágrimas (‘llorar mucho’).

Meaning *This noun, which is neutral in Latin, has been used in both genders in Spanish. In current Spanish it is masculine (...) but among sea people (sailors, fishermen, etc.) it is frequent to use it in the femenine, which is also the case in poetry*.

Comment: I have just had a couple of Spanish lessons by now, so I'm not sure if I understand your answer: Both articles can be used, but "le" is more commonly used?

Comment: @MartinThoma oh, I forgot you asked in English. I just translated the relevant parts into that language. And yes, it is more common to use _el_.

Comment: Do you want to expand a bit on the sentence about stressed and unstressed initial _a_ for @MartinThoma benefit?

Comment: There is "el sartén" as well, even though sartén is femenine.

Comment: @JMVanPelt muchas gracias por [las correcciones](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/19668/revisions) entiendo pues que lo correcto es decir _begin_ y _use_ en lugar de _start_ y _usage_.

Comment: @fedorqui _usage_ no está mal, de hecho es lo correcto como sustantivo (ver acepción 1.1 [aquí](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/usage)). Lo que no es correcto (que yo sepa) es la construcción _it is [adjective] the [noun] of_, debería ser _it is [adjective] [inf. verb]_ o _the [noun] is [adjective]_, entre otras opciones.

Comment: Even if **la azúcar** is correct it sound terrible to me and will also sound terrible to a lot of people. If you want to avoid having to explain that "la" is also correct I'd recommend you to use the most popular form **"el azúcar"**

Answer (score 8):

To complete fedorqui's answer, there are a few more nouns which can be used indistinctly in the masculine or feminine form. They are called "sustantivos ambiguos" (see item 1(c) here: [géneros del sustantivo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg)). It should be noted that nouns are not considered to be ambiguous if their meaning changes depending on the gender used, as in this case we would be dealing with different nouns: *el cólera* (the disease) / *la cólera* (a state of mind) - *el editorial* (an article) - *la editorial* (a publishing house)

Comment: I mean, they are grammatically, not semantically, ambiguous. "El mar" and "el mar" mean exactly the same thing (the only difference being that "la mar" is used mostly in poetry).

Comment: And **lente**, **calor**, **puente** ,...

Comment: Did you really mean to say "puente"? (http://dle.rae.es/?id=UZtOEos)

Comment: Yet another one: **crin** (http://dle.rae.es/?id=BGrSZka)

Answer (score 6):

The big authority on Spanish, the RAE, [lists](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4gcuzQk) the word as

> nombre masculino o femenino.

But for me personally a bigger authority are the authors of books in Spanish over the decades and [they hardly ever use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el%20az%C3%BAcar%2Cla%20az%C3%BAcar&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=10&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cel%20az%C3%BAcar%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bel%20az%C3%BAcar%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEl%20az%C3%BAcar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cla%20az%C3%BAcar%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bla%20az%C3%BAcar%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLa%20az%C3%BAcar%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bla%20Az%C3%BAcar%3B%2Cc0) (nowadays at least) "la azúcar":

[image]

Comment: Google ngrams ... I could have thought of that (+1)

Answer (score -1):

Native speaker here; though I appreciate the very thorough answers above that discuss if "azúcar" is feminine, masculine or neutral and what article corresponds to the grammatical gender, the actual reason why you'll see it written or spoken as "el azúcar" is due to trying to avoid the cacophony that using two stressed "a" sounds in "la azúcar" would have (same is the case for "el águila" vs "la águila" or "el agua" vs. "la agua"). There's a more thorough writeup I just googled here: https://myspanishwordoftheday.com/category/vicios-linguisticos/

Comment: The first _a_ is not stressed in _azúcar_ so what are you trying to say?

Comment: agree with @mdewey This is wrong. The examples of _agua águila, etc_ are right, however _azúcar_ has stress on the **ú** (nota que se escribe con tilde en la u)