# Género de ciertas palabras

Tags: género, artículos

He oído las palabras "azúcar" y "mar" ir acompañadas de los artículos "el" "la" indiscriminadamente. Tanto "la azúcar" como "el azúcar" lo he escuchado, y como el artículo da el género, me hace dudar de cuál sea el género de cada una de estas palabras. Que artículo debería usarse para cada palabra? o se pueden usar ambos?

Comment: Hay preguntas muy parecidas que tienen que ver con ["el agua"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=el+agua+), como  por ejemplo [Why is “agua” masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? “El agua” / “Las aguas”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/44/5481) y es posible que tu pregunta sea un duplicado de [¿Es “la azúcar” o “el azúcar”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19666/5481) y [What are the differences between “el mar” and “la mar”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2536/5481)

Comment: @Diego entendi que cambia el articulo cuando la palabra esta en femenino y empieza con "a", se cambia para el articulo "el" por ser cacofonia basicamente. Pero igual es correcto decir "la agua" o "la azucar"?

Comment: "la agua" o "la azucar" no es correcto. Hay más preguntas, que explican porqué es "**el** aguila blanc**a**", por ejemplo o cuando puedes tener "la" + algo que empieza por "a". Luego saco tiempo y las busco.